# Setting collation for a column in SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql, sql-server-2016

I am testing below code for collation.

```
declare @table table
               (
                    col1 varchar(10) collate Latin1_General_CS_AS 
                    -- modified for column
               )

insert into @table 
values('abcd')

declare @table1 table
                (
                    col2 varchar(10) 
                    --database default(collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS)
                )

insert into @table1
values('abcd')

-- executing this results in an error 'Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" and "Latin1_General_CS_AS" in the equal to operation.'

select * 
from @table a 
join @table1 b on a.col1 = b.col2 

--executing below works fine
select * 
from @table a 
join @table1 b on a.col1 collate Latin1_General_CS_AS  = b.col2 

--executing below again throws error
select * 
from @table a 
join @table1 b on a.col1 collate Latin1_General_CS_AS  = b.col2 collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
```

Need to understand, though I am specifying collation at table variable, it still results in an error.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You only specify the `collate` on one side of the comparison (doesn't matter which side).

```
--executing below works fine
select * from @table a join @table1 b
on a.col1 collate Latin1_General_CS_AS  = b.col2 

--executing below also works fine
select * from @table a join @table1 b
on a.col1 = b.col2 collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
```

You can not specify a comparison that is at the same time two different collations, as you have in your final example (...CS_AS & ...CI_AS).

Comment: So even specifying it at creating tables wont work, we still need to mention that in where clause?

Comment: @omkar you have to pick one collation to be used on both sides of the comparison when both columns have different collations. -- Specifying the collation at the table level will let you set the default collation for comparisons with string literals though.  http://rextester.com/ZPF30783

Comment: @omkar you only need to specify it when the two sides of the join clause use different collations.  In your case, `a` and `b` use different collations so you have to specify which one to use.

Comment: You should use the same collation for all the char columns of a given database unless there is a specific reason for not doing it (like having some columns for text in a different language not supported by the default collation).

Answer (score 0):

Basic principle is you have to make collation of columns same for comparison work properly.

If a.col1 collation is `Latin1_General_CS_AS` then
you can use one of them

- on a.col1 = b.col2 collate Latin1_General_CS_AS
- on a.col1 collate Latin1_General_CS_AS  = b.col2
- a.col1 collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI  = b.col2 collate
  SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI ( you can change both side as long as it is the same )